# Xen virtual guest having dropped packets

Tags: virtual-machines, xen

I have noticed dropped packets on my Xen virtual guest. Checking with main server no dropped packets observed. What could be causing this?

Im using 4.9.112-32.el7.x86_64

[image]

[image]

Added new info :
[image]

Comment: A bad NIC configuration on the host for the VM or in the VM can cause this

Comment: Dropped packets can mean many things. Do you have a firewall enabled on that machine? Because dropping packets is pretty common as a firewall rule instead of rejecting them. Try `ufw status` and `iptables -S` on the client

Comment: ufw is status is disabled.